# POST to nested RESTful resources with $resource parameter mismatch - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I'm trying to using the `$resource` library of angular, to POST data to a nested resource.

My following nested resource of `event` looks like so

- `events/:eventId/match` - POST
- `events/:eventId/match` - GET
- `events/:eventId/match/:matchId` - GET

I set up a service with angular

```
app.factory('EventService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {

            var Event = $resource('/events/:eventId', {eventId: '@id'},
                          {
                            createMatches: {
                               url: '/events/:eventId/match',
                               method: 'POST'
                            }
                        );

            return {

                 createMatches: function(data,event_id) {

                      var data.eventId = event_id;
                      return Event.createMatches(data).$promise;

                 } 
            }

});
```

Controller where it has been called:

```
app.controller('EventController', ['$scope','EventService', function($scope,EventService) {

    $scope.create = function(event_id,title,description) {

        EventService.createMatches({
            title:title,
            description: description
        },event_id).then(function(result) {

            console.log('event_created', result);
        })
    }

}]);
```

**Problem**

When I send the request to the server I expect the url that looks like so: `/events/10/match`

But instead the resource doesn't add the `eventId` as a parameter of the url but add it as a parameter of the request, for this reason my call fail because the url looks like so:  `/events/match`.

I can't understand why it doesn't bind the `:eventId` to the url. Any suggest will be appreciated.

Comment: share the code how you calling this factory?

Comment: Done, I update the question with the function where I call the factory

Comment: does the object have a property `id` ?

Comment: what version of angular are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are missing your second parameter decalaration, [as per this link for the actions you are defining](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

```
app.factory('EventService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {

    var Event = $resource('/events/:eventId', {eventId: '@id'},
                  {
                    createMatches: {
                       url: '/events/:eventId/match',
                       method: 'POST',
                       params: {eventId: '@id'}
                    }
                );

    return {

         createMatches: function(data,event_id) {

              var data.eventId = event_id;
              return Event.createMatches(data).$promise;

         } 
    }

});
```